# Unit test using class with RestTemplate injected with java and spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito, resttemplate

I'm running unit testing with a class that has the injected RestTemplate and only when I run the tests does RestTemplate get null after consuming the API I'm consuming.

```
class ReceitaWsIntegrationImpl implements ReceitaWsIntegration {

  private static final String URL_RECEITA_WS_CNPJ
    = "https://www.receitaws.com.br/v1/cnpj";

  private final RestTemplate restTemplate;

  @Override
  public void findByCnpj(String cnpj) {
    ResponseEntity<CnpjResource> forEntity = restTemplate.getForEntity(
      URL_RECEITA_WS_CNPJ.concat("/").concat(cnpj), CnpjResource.class);
  }
}
```

Test class:

```
public class ReceitaWsIntegrationImplTest extends TestSupport {

private static final String CNPJ = "27865757000102";
private static final String URL_RECEITA_WS_CNPJ = "https://www.receitaws.com.br/v1/cnpj/";
@Mock
private RestTemplate restTemplate;
private ReceitaWsIntegration receitaWsIntegration;

    @Override
    public void init() {
        receitaWsIntegration = new ReceitaWsIntegrationImpl(restTemplate);
    }

    @Test
    public void should_find_company_by_cnpj() {
        receitaWsIntegration.findByCnpj(CNPJ);

        InOrder inOrder = inOrder(restTemplate);

        inOrder.verify(restTemplate, times(1))
            .getForEntity(URL_RECEITA_WS_CNPJ.concat(CNPJ), CnpjResource.class);
        inOrder.verifyNoMoreInteractions();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use `RefelectionTestUtils.setField` https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/util/ReflectionTestUtils.html#setField-java.lang.Class-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-

Comment: annotate `init` method with `@Before` you should be good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Frankly speaking I do not see anything in `findByCnpj()` that requires its own unit-test. I don't think you need to test `RestTemplate.getForEntity()` method since it was tested many times by Spring developers (and testers). And there is no additional logic in `findByCnpj()`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your test does not create a `RestTemplate` object because there is no code that processes the annotation `@Mock`. There are different ways for creating the mock. E.g. you can init the mock in the `init` method.

```
@Override
public void init() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    receitaWsIntegration = new ReceitaWsIntegrationImpl(restTemplate);
}
```

For more options have a look at the [Mockito's Javadoc](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/1.10.19).